# Verify that $\Theta|X \sim Be(\alpha + S, \beta + n - S)$

Tags: probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I'm learning about Bayesian statistics and I've come across the following example:

Let \begin{split}X_1, ..., X_n \stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim} Ber\,(\theta),\\
\Theta \sim Be(\alpha, \beta). \end{split}

We have $$f_{\Theta|X}(\theta|x) = \dfrac{f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)\,f_{\Theta}(\theta)}{\int f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)\,f_{\Theta}(\theta)\,d\theta}$$

My book claims that in this case $\Theta |X \sim Be(\alpha + S,\beta + n -S)$. I tried to check this and I got the following result:
$$f_{\Theta|X}(\theta|x) = \frac{\theta^{S+\alpha -1}(1-\theta)^{n- S + \beta -1}}{\int\theta^{S+\alpha -1}(1-\theta)^{n- S + \beta -1} d\theta},$$

where $S$ is the numbers of times that $X_i$ equals $1$, that is $S = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i$. I've my results are correct, I don't see how $\Theta |X \sim Be(\alpha + S,\beta + n -S)$. I understand that I'm missing something, since the exponentials of $\theta$ and $(1-\theta)$ in the fraction match the supposed distribution exactly.

**Question:** Why is $\Theta |X \sim Be(\alpha + S,\beta + n -S)$?

Comment: Wait, you know that $$f_{\Theta|X}(\theta|x) = c(x)\theta^{\color{red}{s+\alpha} -1}(1-\theta)^{\color{blue}{n- s + \beta} -1}$$ for some constant $c(x)$ independent of $\theta$. This is exactly what being Beta$(\color{red}{s+\alpha},\color{blue}{n- s + \beta})$ means, no?

Comment: Complementing what @Did said, you should note that, although $\int{\theta^{S+\alpha-1}(1-\theta)^{n-S+\beta-1}d\theta}$ has a symbol "$\theta$", it is not a function of $\theta$. In that context, $\theta$ is a variable of integration.

Comment: Indeed, to repeat @madprobs important point, the denominator $$\int\theta^{S+\alpha -1}(1-\theta)^{n- S + \beta -1} d\theta$$ should be written $$\int_0^1t^{s+\alpha -1}(1-t)^{n- s + \beta -1} dt$$ or any other equivalent formula not involving $\theta$.